# Permission denied for Browsing HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, permission-denied

I'm learning `Hadoop` and `Spark` environment and I installed both environment with success.

But, when I want to go to HDFS management (`localhost:50070/explorer`) and I want to click on `tmp`, I get this issue :

```
Permission denied: user=dr.who, access=READ_EXECUTE, inode="/tmp":valentin:supergroup:drwx-wx-wx
```

[image]

I tried to change permissions with :

```
hdfs dfs –chmod –R 755 /valentin
```

But I get :

```
–chmod: Unknown command
```

It strange because I have :

```
valentin@hadoop:~/hadoop-2.9.0$ bin/hdfs dfs -ls /
18/02/06 11:55:38 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 1 items
drwx-wx-wx   - valentin supergroup          0 2018-02-06 11:36 /tmp
```

Could you help me to find a solution in order to upload .txt file into my tmp directory ?

I have in .bashrc :

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/valentin/hadoop-2.9.0
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"

export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
```

Comment: It's `hadoop fs -chmod`. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#chmod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is from Bash, not the Hadoop CLI

Your hyphen is wrong. You gave `–` and it expected `-` (yes there is a difference)

This commonly happens when you copy terminal commands off random websites that don't have good code formatting.

And you gave the wrong directory if you wanted to set /tmp

You might also want to find out what `"fs.permissions.umask-mode"` is set to in hdfs site

It is set to 022 by default, but looks like you got it to be 011

tmp can be globally RWX

```
hadoop dfs -chmod -R 1777 /tmp
```

---

Once you have all that working again, if you want to actually run mapreduce and stuff, you need to

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/valentin
hadoop fs -chmod -R 750 /user/valentin
hadoop fs -chown -R  valentin  /user/valentin
```